# PyInstaller packed PySide6 application Cannot load qtquick2plugin.dll

Tags: qt, qml, pyinstaller, pyside6

I have a PySide6 + QML application to pack to exe file with PyInstaller.

Here's my code:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Motor"
    width: 500
    height: 600
    visible: true

    maximumHeight: height
    maximumWidth: width

    minimumHeight: height
    minimumWidth: width
}
```

main.py

```
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys 
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine(parent=app)
  
    engine.load("main.qml")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

motor.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['E:\\Projects\\motor\\GUI'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('main.qml', '.'), ('settings.ini', '.')],
             hiddenimports=['PySide6.QtCore', 'PySide6.QtGui', 'PySide6.QtQml'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='MotorGUI',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='MotorGUI')
```

After pack with `pyinstaller motor.spec`, I copied `plugins`, `qml` and `translations` folder from python/site-pack/PySide6 folder to the exe's PySide6 folder.

When I run the exe file, I got:

```
QQmlApplicationEngin failed to load component
file:///E:/Projects/motor/GUI/dist/MotorGUI/main.qml:1:1: Cannot load library E:\Projects\motor\GUI\dist\MotorGUI\PySide6\qml\QtQuick\qtquick2plugin.dll
```

The `qtquick2plugin.dll` actually exists.

my python version is 3.8.6

PySide==6.0.0

pyinstaller==4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the root cause. It lacks of dll of QT.

I fix this by copying all .dll file in the pyside Qt folder to the exe's folder.

Then it runs perfectly.

After that, I mamually remove redundant dll one by one to determine the minimal requirements.

Finally add the dll in spec file

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller (as of 4.2) does not yet support PySide6.

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5414